# FINDSTR using variable from text file (Batch,Scripting)

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I have a statement, which removes a specific string out of a text file, although how can I define this string from a text file.

E.g. the text file has one line of text and I efectively want that text to go inbetween `"/c:"<HERE>" >>"`

The statement is below

```
type ignore_tmp.lst | findstr /v /c:"%ignore%p" >> ignore_tmp_.lst
```

So I think the real question is, if I echoed the text file, maybe using the type command, how could I set the output as a variable?

Comment: So I think the real question is, if I echoed the text file, maybe using the type command, how could I set the output as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The for command can do what you're looking for, both by reading the file itself or by capturing the output of the type or findstr command, like you said.

```
C:\>echo test1 > input.txt
C:\>for /f "delims=" %a in (input.txt) do @set input_content=%a
C:\>echo %input_content%
test1
C:\>echo test2 > input.txt
C:\>for /f "delims=" %a in ('type input.txt') do @set input_content=%a
C:\>echo %input_content%
test2
```